# Simultaneous commands

Tags: bash, date

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date +%T &
Hours=`date +"%H"` &
Minutes=`date +"%M"` & 
Seconds=`date +"%S"`

echo "$Hours:$Minutes:$Seconds"
```

The objective is to `echo date` two times and then take out hours, minutes, seconds and calculate how many seconds elapsed between those two commands. So my solution is to write hours, minutes, seconds into variables, then work with those variables.

Problem: `echo` only echoes seconds which means my interpretation of `&` is wrong.

1. How can I fix the `&` problem? I need those commands to run simultaneously so I can check.
2. `date +%s` apparently won't work on certain inputs like:

`Wed Mar  4 10:34:59 2015
Wed Mar  4 10:35:08 2015`

Will give result of `00:00:01` instead of `00:00:09` or:

`Wed Mar  4 10:34:59 2015
Wed Mar  4 17:43:08 2015`

will give the result of `12:13:14` instead of `07:08:09`. Is it true? Or can I use `date +%s` and then decrease those two outputs?

Comment: This looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You really want to find out how to calculate the duration of something (the actual problem, "X") but you are asking about how to run several date commands simultaneously (your attempted solution "Y").

Comment: Assignments in a background process are limited to that process. They do not appear in the calling script. Besides, there's no need to run `date` in the background; it doesn't take that long to run.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run the commands simultaneously. Run just one command:

```
read hours minutes seconds < <( date '+%H %M %S' )
```

But it can be even simpler: just use the `+%s` format to get number of seconds since the epoch. You'll get two numbers you can safely subtract.

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)
sleep 10
end=$(date +%s)

echo The command took $(( end - start )) seconds.
```

The easiest way is to use the shell variable $SECONDS.

> Each time this parameter is referenced, the number of seconds since shell invocation is returned.  If a value is assigned to SECONDS, the value returned upon
>                 subsequent references is the number of seconds since the  assignment  plus  the
>                 value  assigned.  If SECONDS is unset, it loses its special properties, even if
>                 it is subsequently reset.

Comment: By running a "set" of commands simultaneously I just wanted to check if I pulled relevant information from the output correctly (aka if I pulled out the correct seconds). And about `+%s` I just wasn't sure because of the note in point 2.

Comment: If all the OP is doing is calculating a duration, I'd use bash's builtin `$SECONDS` instead

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman `date` returns so fast that it is probably *slower* to try to run them in parallel, due to the bookkeeping the shell needs to do to manage background jobs.

Answer (score -1):

the main problem is that in this case the command `date` will be executed tree times to get the values..

so you don't need to execute the commad date too many times

```
#!/bin/bash

#date +%T &
function myTime(){

now=`date +"%H:%M:%S" &` 
}

myTime
s1=`echo $now | cut -d":" -f2`
myTime
s2=`echo $now | cut -d":" -f2`

echo "s1[$s1] - s2[$s2]"
```

Then you can apply your rules to verify the time elapsed

Regards

Claudio

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are lots of poor practices in this answer: unnecessary background processes, inefficient use of `echo | cut`, using a global variable, backquotes instead of `$(...)`...